# Scan multiple pages at once

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have an puppeteer problem. I have an array with links

```
let links = ["...", "...", "..."];
```

Thats about 30 links. I wanted to scrape them all at once with `Promise.all()`

```
let descriptions = await Promise.all(
    links.map((url) => getDescription(page, url))
);
```

Every page has an description but for some reason my `descriptions` array is populated with 30 same description.

Why is that? Do i need to scrape one by one or?

The description function:

```
export async function getDescription(page, url) {
  await page.goto(url);
  let selector = ".C4VMK > span";
  return page.$eval(selector, (handle) => handle.textContent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have managed it like this:

I create a new tab and open that URL from that

```
export async function getDescription(browser, url) {
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  let selector = ".C4VMK > span";
  let result = await page.$eval(selector, (handle) => handle.textContent);
  page.close();
  return result;
}
```